# Vue lazyloading gets triggered when adding dynamic class to <main>

Tags: vue.js, lazy-loading

I am adding a 'sticky-header' class to my  dynamically, but when its sticky i obviously also need to add padding to my  so the content doesnt go behind the header.

The problem is that when adding the padding via class-binding`(v-bind:class="{'fixed-header': stickyHeader}")`on scroll, this reloads all the lazy-loaded images (that are lazy loaded using vue lazy)

This makes all images go from `loading` to `loaded` in a split second, but its very noticable.

`stickyHeader`is a boolean that gets recalculated on scroll, if the window is scrolled past a certain element (with a eventlistener on scroll: `checkHeader()`)

```
 checkHeader() {
            var elementTarget = document.getElementById("notice");

             if(window.scrollY > (elementTarget.offsetTop + elementTarget.offsetHeight)){
                 this.stickyHeader = true;
             }
            else{
                this.stickyHeader = false;
            }
        }
```

Anyone know what exactly triggers the images to go back to 'loading' for a split second?

Comment: Can you add some code?
My guess is `stickyHeader` is a computed property, your component might be re-rendering when you are computing for applying this class.

Comment: @UtsavPatel i have added the code that gets called onscroll, it is indeed a computed property, but why would the component re-render?

Comment: Computed property runs everytime whenever your data or props change. Re-rendering means applying the latest changes to dom.

Comment: @UtsavPatel what would be the best way for me to dynamically add a class, but not make it re-render. Or is that not possible?

Comment: @UtsavPatel i found a solution. im answering it

Comment: You should set `data` property in computed. 
You should only derive from it. 

`this.stickyHeader = true;` this part is the cause.

Answer (score -1):

To solve this instead of dynamically binding the class with `v-bind` i simply add it in the scroll listener method with basic javascript, now it doesnt rerender :) !